With urxvt: unable to prevent title in title bar from being overwritten
I'm using urxvt version 9.22 under Ubuntu 20.04.1.
Even though I use -title MYTITLE on the urxvt command line, and even though I set the following Xresource ...
URxvt.insecure: false

... the title in the titlebar still gets overwritten if any command that is run within urxvt sends out the appropriate title-change escape sequence.
Is there any way in urxvt to specify that -title specified on the command line will never be able to be overwritten via any escape sequence?
Thank you in advance for any thoughts and ideas.

The resource insecure and the corresponding command line parameter -insecure only affect the sequences which produce output, like the unofficial DSR 7 extension:
case 7:         /* unofficial extension */
  if (option (Opt_insecure))
    tt_printf ("%-.250s\012", rs[Rs_display_name]);
    break;

From the source code:
case XTerm_title:
  set_title (str);
  break;

and the definition of set_title:
void
rxvt_term::set_title (const char *str)
{
  set_mbstring_property (XA_WM_NAME, str);
#if ENABLE_EWMH
  set_utf8_property (xa[XA_NET_WM_NAME], str);
#endif
}

it can be seen that the option(Opt_insecure) value isn't checked at all by URxvt when setting the title (and icon, etc).
The answer seems to be that the behavior described in this question could only be achieved by modifying the source code of URxvt to take the option(Opt_insecure) into account when setting the title.

I was thinking that the only solution might be to modify the urxvt code base. Now I see that this is indeed the case. Thank you very much! I accept this as the Answer to my question.
